# Django query limit and streamingHttpResponse

Tags: django

I am filtering a model's objects by foreignkey. The result is 30.000 records and my shared host server gives memory error.

How can I write partial queries say a query limits to 1000 results?

Do you think using StreamingHttpResponse into a template helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit queries quite easily in Django, using Python's array-splicing notation. You can use this on any query. Here are some examples:

```
# Will return only the first 1000 objects in the query
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(some_field=some_value)[:1000]  

# Will return only the first 500 objects
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()[:500] 

# Will return the first 1000 objects of the filtered query ordered by the objects pk
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(some_field=some_value).order_by('pk')[:1000] 

# Will return the 25th through 50th object
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()[25:50] 

# Will return all objects but the first 10
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()[10:]
```

Django is smart about this, and will only query what is needed and then stop, rather than gathering the entire query and then chopping off the rest.

See the [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) for more details.

Comment: How about using this splicing in a for loop?  Does django empty the cache after each query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method. It will iterate over a Django Queryset ordered by the primary key

```
def queryset_iterator(queryset, chunksize=1000):
    pk = 0
    last_pk = queryset.order_by("-pk")[0].pk
    queryset = queryset.order_by("pk")
    while pk < last_pk:
        for row in queryset.filter(pk__gt=pk)[:chunksize]:
            pk = row.pk
            yield row
        gc.collect()
```